# Searching in Database and Some Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database

I am trying to get data from a database file (.mdb) using textbox, button and gridview. The button code wasn't working and had some errors. Therefore, I changed it to prevent possible errors. I have a problem and could not solve it.

What I want:

- If the database does not include "testpurpose", Label1 will show. But, I do not know how to add below code? Do you know an example to look into it?
- **DONE - Thank you Egbert**. When I write a string like "ab12" on textbox and click on button, It gives entries that starts with "ab12" such as "ab12", "ab125", "ab12cs", etc. The database includes all of them, but it should search string "ab12" and give string with its entry. How to show the result of only written string?

By the way

- "Pass" contains numbers and letters.
- Label1 text is "Invalid Entry" to show errors.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string testpurpose;

    if (TextBox1.Text == "" || TextBox1.Text.Length < 5)
    {

        Label1.Visible = true;
        GridView1.Visible = false;
    }

    else
    {
        testpurpose = TextBox1.Text;
        Label1.Visible = false;
        GridView1.Visible = true;

        AccessDataSource1.SelectParameters["Pass"].DefaultValue = testpurpose;
    }

}
```

Here is database query:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/Database2.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Pass], [IDNumber] FROM [GENERAL] WHERE ([Pass] LIKE '%' + ? + '%')">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Pass" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Not sure what the question is. I think we need to see the db query. (?)

Comment: In your SelectCommand you use WHERE ([Pass] LIKE '%?%' which means that you select everything that contains your string. Try using WHERE ([Pass] = '?'

Comment: @wazz Hello, I edited my question and added db code.

Comment: @JohnB I am going to look into it.